# Implementation of Cognitive Services in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, machine-translation

I need to know about Microsoft Cognitive Service. I read articles related to it and need to implement these kind of features in SharePoint 2013 or O365 (SharePoint Online).

- Knowledge Exploration Services (KES)
- Search document with Translated Keywords. E.g. in SharePoint there is a document in French, if I search contents in English keyword then that French document should be coming in search results.
- Auto Suggestion: Need to implement auto suggestive query result in search box as drop down.

Please let me know if this type of Microsoft solution are available or can be implemented in SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

It's a broad but an interesting topic. I'll share some of my thoughts that could be implemented to SharePoint Online.

> Search document with Translated Keywords. E.g. in SharePoint there is a document in French, if I search contents in English keyword then that French document should be coming in search results.

This is a limitation of the product, as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805087.aspx#bkmkMUILimitations). There can be implemented a "midway" solution, which consists of creating synonyms (translations of words from non-default to default language) for taxonomy terms, for list titles and for site titles. This should enhance the searchability within SharePoint. Some further thoughts have been shared e.g. in [here](https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/sharepoint-multilingual-sites-what-you-need-to-know).

> Auto Suggestion: Need to implement auto suggestive query result in search box as drop down.

Query suggestions can be implemented to SharePoint through the O365 Admin Center. The process is however quite manually implemented and maintained. This is described in [Customize query suggestions in SharePoint search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-query-suggestions-in-SharePoint-search-9ef0f859-3b92-41e9-b393-cb43d6094c7b).

> Knowledge Exploration Services (KES)

I swapped this as the last to detail, as [Microsoft's Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/?v=17.25b) (MCS) consists of 21 APIs in total, including "Language Understanding Intelligence Service", "Computer Vision API", "Academic Knowledge API" and "Bing Autosuggest". Now these APIs may offer undiscovered possibilities for the above mentioned, which basically could change the limitations as we have got used to know them. However, despite the fact that we have known the existence of MCS for over ½ a year so far, there hasn't been much to any input about the possibilities to implement the solutions to the SharePoint's context.

KES has a strong similarity to what's known as metadata in SharePoint's terms. Its features - in theory - could allow us to e.g. parse the data of SharePoint to add and revise the metadata for existing items. For what I've read, the APIs are not quite yet in the state which would encourage next to any of us to revolutionize our way of using SP. The given example of adding metadata to items is an often faced challenge, but none of the APIs are exactly designed for that purpose. Additionally, the built-in machine learning has been commented to work with a limited functionality, meaning some of the recognition/identification, reading and context-mapping don't match the real world expectations. Finally, handling the output of the API in SharePoint requires a rather manual approach with tools such as SharePoint's PnP components.

---

To summarize, existing solutions of implementing MCS to SharePoint are very limited, and - with a touch of a personal opinion - one shouldn't get too excited about the features and their functionality when an organization's requirements are set on the table as limitations shall be expected.